# List table contents depending on other content

Tags: php, mysql

I've been creating a users online page, what I've done is set it to when a user logs in, they have a column in the database called "Loggedin" that changes to "yes". When user logs out, that column changes to "no". All fine and good.

What I want to do is list the amount of users who have "loggedin" set to "yes". I know it's very simple as I've done it before but I can't remember!!

I remember I have to join the tables and get the rows like this

```
 $whoisloggedin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT loggedin,username FROM stats LEFT JOIN users ON     stats.id=users.id WHERE loggedin='yes'");
 $howmany = mysqli_num_rows($whoisloggedin);
 echo $howmany;
```

But how can I list the usernames with the same ID's as loggedin being "yes"?

Sorry if I've worded it badly!

edit - the "echo $howmany" returns the correct amount being 1 as I'm the only one logged in on the local server

EDIT

FULL CODE

```
<?php 
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");

$whoisloggedin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT loggedin,username FROM stats LEFT JOIN users ON     stats.id=users.id WHERE loggedin='yes'");

$howmany = mysqli_num_rows($whoisloggedin);
echo $howmany,"<br>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin) ) {
$test = $row['username'];
 echo $test,"<br>";
 }

include ("footer.php");

?>
```

It shows:

```
4 (the amount of users with "Loggedin" set to "yes"
Kenazz (my username)
```

So it only echoes just mine :(

Comment: Are you struggling with the SQL or how to output it visually?

Comment: @DrSchizo Why? I have everything there don't I? Isn't it just like LIST BY username WHERE loggedin = 'yes' or something?

Comment: So you want to iterate each row and display on screen right?

Comment: what do you want if the join is correct then you need to iterate and show the result

Comment: Yeah, the join is correct, it's just showing the result that I need help with

Comment: Had a look and I was way off with "list" lol

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

```
while ($row = $whoisloggedin->fetch_assoc() ) {
$usersArray[] = $row['username'];
}
```

and then do what you want with usersArray

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that :) I do it procedural rather than object orientated though

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. What am I supposed to echo? I echoed the $row['username'] but it doesn't work if there's more than one username

Comment: if there is more than 1 username than you either need to put your echo after $usersArray in the while statement, or if you want it somewhere else, use a for loop.

Comment: what actually is that "$usersArray"? The empty brackets mean I can't echo it, please see edit

Comment: it contains the array of usernames, if you want you can do it like:  $usersArray[$i] = $row['username'];  and then to get them all out use a for loop, for($y=0;$y<$i;$y++) { echo $usersArray[$i];

Comment: Sorry yeah that makes sense. Besides the "$i" part, I knew before I tried it I would get undefined variable and that's what I got. I've changed it to just $usersArray but the other 3 usernames show as "Null" after a var_dump

Comment: Showing as null because I had the wrong ID's! lol but now they're formatted as one word, rather than a list

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work. I do not what you have been jion while table is only 1.

```
$whoisloggedin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT loggedin,username FROM stats WHERE loggedin='yes'");
 $howmany = mysqli_num_rows($whoisloggedin);
 echo $howmany;
```

Comment: That is not the problem, the problem is, I don't know how to display multiple results

Answer (score 0):

FINAL ANSWER

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin) ) {
$usersArray = $row['username'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($usersArray);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

Found from a previous stackoverflow question :)